# Is it possible to create multiple columns that are based on each other?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this DF:

```
Range = np.arange(0,10,1)

Table = pd.DataFrame({"Row": Range})
```

Now I'd like to add 2 new columns that are based on each other -

For example -

```
Table["A"]=np.where(Table["B"].shift(1)>0,1,0)
Table["B"]=np.where(Table["A"]==1,1,0)
```

In Excel for example there isn't an error for a circle of invalid data.
I wonder if that is possible on df in python.

Thanks.

Comment: No. What purpose could this have?

Comment: How  would `np.where(Table["B"].shift(1)>0,1,0)` work when `Table["B"]` does not even exist yet?

Comment: I understand that Table["B"] doesn't exist. Buy maybe creating both of the columns using for loop would help here.

Comment: And the usefulness of these two self-referential columns unconnected to anything else would be what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an iterative approach, initializing `B` to something (e.g., all items equal to `None` or `1` or `0`, or some other initialization pattern), setting `A` as in your question, then looping and updating `A` and `B` until each converges or a maximum iteration threshold is reached:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Range = np.arange(0,4,1)

Table = pd.DataFrame({"Row": Range})
print(Table)

for pair in [(np.nan, np.nan), (None, None), (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]:
    print(f'\npair is {pair}')
    Table["B"] = np.where(Table["Row"] % 2, pair[0], pair[1])
    Table["A"] = np.where(Table["B"].shift(1) > 0, 1, 0)
    i = 0
    prevA, prevB = None, None
    while prevA is None or not prevB.equals(Table["B"]) or not prevA.equals(Table["A"]):
        if i >= 20:
            print('max iterations exceeded')
            break
        print(f'iteration {i}')
        print(Table)
        i += 1
        prevA, prevB = Table["A"].copy(), Table["B"].copy()
        Table["A"] = np.where(Table["B"].shift(1) > 0, 1, 0)
        Table["B"] = np.where(Table["A"] == 1, 1, 0)
```

Note that with the example logic from OP, this does indeed seem to converge for a few initialization patterns for `B` (at least it does using a shorter input array of length 4).

Sample output:

```
pair is (nan, nan)
iteration 0
   Row   B  A
0    0 NaN  0
1    1 NaN  0
2    2 NaN  0
3    3 NaN  0
iteration 1
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0

pair is (None, None)
iteration 0
   Row     B  A
0    0  None  0
1    1  None  0
2    2  None  0
3    3  None  0
iteration 1
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0

pair is (0, 0)
iteration 0
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0

pair is (0, 1)
iteration 0
   Row  B  A
0    0  1  0
1    1  0  1
2    2  1  0
3    3  0  1
iteration 1
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  1  1
2    2  0  0
3    3  1  1
iteration 2
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  1  1
3    3  0  0
iteration 3
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  1  1
iteration 4
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0

pair is (1, 0)
iteration 0
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  1  0
2    2  0  1
3    3  1  0
iteration 1
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  1  1
3    3  0  0
iteration 2
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  1  1
iteration 3
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0

pair is (1, 1)
iteration 0
   Row  B  A
0    0  1  0
1    1  1  1
2    2  1  1
3    3  1  1
iteration 1
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  1  1
2    2  1  1
3    3  1  1
iteration 2
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  1  1
3    3  1  1
iteration 3
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  1  1
iteration 4
   Row  B  A
0    0  0  0
1    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
3    3  0  0
```